# Define default value for inherited class using lombok

Tags: java, inheritance, quarkus, lombok

So I am developing a notification service which, for now, only has a `Notification` and an `Email` entity, where Email extends Notification.

The `Notification` entity has a column named `type` which stores the type of the notification (ie: EMAIL, MESSAGE, PUSH, etc) and I want to know if there is a way to define a default value for the `type` column for each of the childs of `Notification` while using lombok.

I see that a common practice is to set the type on the constructor, like this:

```
public Email() {
    setType("EMAIL");
}
```

But I am using the builder from lombok to instatiate `Email`, like this:

```
public static Email fromEmailRequest(final EmailRequest emailRequest) {
        if (Objects.isNull(emailRequest)) {
            return Email.builder().build();
        }
        Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<>(emailRequest.getRecipients());
        return Email.builder()
                .content(emailRequest.getContent())
                .recipients(Lists.newArrayList(set))
                .sender(emailRequest.getSender())
                .subject(emailRequest.getSubject())
                .type(NotificationTypeEnum.EMAIL)
                .build();
}
```

The approach I am using now sets the type in the request DTO mapper, but I think this logic should be somewhere in the entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is a better way, but you can create a constructor inside your `Notification` class which has the type as parameter and then manually create an all args constructor for your `Email` class. Lombok will use this constructor for the builder instead of generating one.

```
public class Notification {

    private final String type;

    protected Notification(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}

@Builder
public class Email extends Notification {

    private String test;

    private Email(String test) {
        super("EMAIL");
        this.test = test;
    }
}
```

---

`@SuperBuilder` is a bit more complex to work with, but the idea is the same. You can still write parts of the code that is normally generated by lombok yourself and change its behavior with your own code.

So you implement the `build` method yourself and set the `type` to `EMAIL`.

```
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public class Email extends Notification {

    private String test;

    public static class EmailBuilderImpl extends EmailBuilder<Email, EmailBuilderImpl> {
        /* Make sure the value is never accidently set to something other than `EMAIL`*/
        @Override
        public EmailBuilderImpl type(String type) {
            if (!type.equals("EMAIL")) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
            return super.type(type);
        }

        public Email build() {
            return new Email(type("EMAIL"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This didnt work. I think lombok didnt recognize the constructor and type just stayed as null. I dont know if this affects but I am using @SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true) on the Email entity, so that I can instatiate all the properties from the email and notigfication together.

Comment: Yes right. I've updated the example.

Comment: This worked perfectly my friend :D I am just going to ask you to edit the first code snnipet (delete the Email class) since it is no longer being used and just leave the bottom snnipet. Maybe merge both into one. Then I approve the answer! :D

Comment: Hey @magicmn I know it past some time but I was going to ask again for you to update your answer as it was ineed helpful! I really want to approve it but the way it was left isnt fully clear :(